# Php find mysql parameters required

Tags: php, mysql

I have done this in c# before and mssql and was wondering if anyone knew how i would do it with mysql and php.

I have a stored procedure. I need to find all the parameters required from the stored procedure. From here I can match up my object to the parameters and pass them into the stored procedure.

This would save me so much time if anyone knows a way it can be done rather than keep repeating myself for every insert.

Basically want to find out the parameters a stored procedure has with php for a mysql database.

Comment: Look at ORMs instead of stored procedures

Comment: why ORMs- surely this is slower and less secure- thought best to have logic on database level for security, speed

Comment: does the `SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS` command work?

Comment: @Matthew Chambers I would say storing any application related business logic in database is a bad idea.

Comment: why is that i have read it is best for security, speed. Although i agree orm best for maintainable and not repeating yourself.

Comment: 1) Security, is one of myths. 2) DB is a bottleneck of almost any application, so I do not see how making it work more can make app faster.

Comment: E_p do you have anything to support this- why is db bottleneck?. I have used linq and orms. i accept maintainability but not security and speed

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies slide 28 ;) This one about security. An as I worked in Istockphoto any speed problem they had was 100% database related.

Comment: what does istockphoto and the big boys use - i.e. facebook orm or stored procs

Comment: No stored procedures for business logic only maintance. Avoid any joins etc. Cache everything. DB layer was ORMish :). There unless something changed withing last year. I left about a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using MySQL's builtin `information_schema` database. This database is used by MySQL itself to store meta informations about schema, tables, columns, ...  **and** procedures :)

Use the following query to get information about all params that belong to a procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`PARAMETERS` 
WHERE `SPECIFIC_NAME` = 'YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME' 
  AND `SPECIFIC_SCHEMA` = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME'
```

Of course you can refine the query.

Comment: I think yes. There is `SHOW PROCEDURE CODE your_procedure` but this will give you the code, not the params (and will only work if mysql is compiled with `--with-debug` was is unlikely by default)

Comment: .net uses SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters think this is the same as above- overhead to database each time

Comment: You mean when you are using .NET together with mysql or mssql? If mysql, it would be interesting to inspect the traffic using wireshark

Comment: i am using php and mysql- remember doing something similar with .net in the past so was wondering what i did and it was to use this SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters

Comment: But you used SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters together with a mssql database, yes?